# Sort JSON object with pug

Tags: node.js, pug, pugjs

Currently I am using this code to Sort the data within nodejs code.

```
const popularPlaces = await Places
.find({location: "New York"})
.sort( { locationscore: -1 } )
```

The code above finds location `New York` and sorts popular places with higher `locationscore` and dumps into `popularPlaces`. This way I can use it on `pug/jade` template like this:

```
each value in popularPlaces
  .h2 Top Popular Places #{value.placename}
```

But I want to do the sorting in `pug/jade` itself... and not by nodejs.

This is the JSON that gets returned by `popularPlaces`

```
[{
    "placename": "Modern Stop", 
    "locationscore": 0.8734, 
},{
    "placename": "Next Coffee", 
    "locationscore": 0.807121, 
},{
    "placename": "Mahattan Bakery", 
    "locationscore": 0.899802, 
},{
    "placename": "Mainland Cafe", 
    "locationscore": 0.801271, 
},{
    "placename": "Combo Boo", 
    "locationscore": 0.808973, 
},{
    "placename": "Baker's Bakery", 
    "locationscore": 0.8123, 
}]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Pls add the JSON given by your database

Comment: @SandeepRanjan I have added the sample JSON data that is returned

Comment: Have you tired myself answer?

Comment: Did my solution work? Just for the good, you must accept the answer if it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
- popularPlaces.sort(function(a, b){ return (a.locationscore > b.locationscore) ? 1 : ((b.locationscore > a.locationscore) ? -1 : 0); })

each value in popularPlaces
  .h2 Top Popular Places #{value.placename}
```